# Qiskit's classifier is not optimising the weights

Tags: qiskit, optimization, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

I am using qiskit's VQC to build a classifier. Dimensionality of the data is 2 and number of classes are 4. The feature map I used is ZZFeatureMap and ansatz is the RealAplitudes. Then entanglement and reps are "full" and 2 respectively for both feature map and ansatz. Optimizer used is 'COBYLA'. Please find below the respective code.

[image]

When I try to fit the classifier, it is not optimising the weights and the loss is always "nan". It is stopping after 7 iterations.

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I train a classifier using qiskit's VQC ? Thank you!

Comment: Try to change your optimizer and see if that changes anything,

Comment: I did, I tried with ADAM and AMSGRAD too. I can't be help but think I am missing something basic somewhere.

Comment: I strongly believe it is to do with the number of classes the dataset has. Upon trying a tutorial of qiskit on this topic, everything worked well until I changed the dataset to include more classes. I have elaborated on this here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/21661/how-to-perform-multi-class-classification-with-qiskits-vqc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with 0.3.0 version of qiskit_machine_learning library. Fix is to install 0.4.0 version. More details about the issue and how to install 0.4.0 is in this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/23948/18574).