# How to perform multi-class classification with qiskit's VQC?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

I am following the tutorial given in qiskit's website [Neural Network Classifier and Regressor](https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/tutorials/02_neural_network_classifier_and_regressor.html). In the first part, classification, the third section refers to qiskit's VQC library. Everything works fine with the given X and y where there are only two classes. I modified the X and y slightly to include four classes instead of two using the following lines:

```
num_inputs = 2
num_samples = 100

X = 2*np.random.rand(num_samples, num_inputs) - 1
y = np.random.choice([0,1,2,3], 100)

y_one_hot = np.zeros(( num_samples, 4 ))
for i in range(len(y)):
    y_one_hot[i, y[i]]=1
```

The rest of the code is untouched. VQC with ZZFeatureMap, RealAmplitudes ansatz, cross_entropy loss function and COBYLA() optimizer.
However, when I try to fit with this new data, the classifier is only running for 5 iterations and the weights are not being changed at all. The loss or objection function's value is always calculated as "nan".

There is a [similar question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/21568/qiskits-classifier-is-not-optimising-the-weights) I had posted about weights not being optimized with VQC, but then I thought it was because of my data or VQC's configuration. After trying this example, I realised it is clearly to do something with multiple classes and not just the classifier's configuration.

Please shine light on how to do multi-class classification using the qiskit's VQC library.

Comment: Here is the code in a colab notebook. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1diZB4EUqaM8Ku4b2y7zbjKnxIxK_7hEv?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved now. The above mentioned problem was an issue with 0.3.0 version qiskit_machine_learning library. You can get more details about the issue and how it has been resolved [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-machine-learning/issues/251).

**TLDR**: Install the 0.4.0 developer's version of qiskit_machine_learning library. Clone this [repository](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-machine-learning) and from with the folder, run `pip install .`